# How do I format xml to be nice in eclipse?

Tags: xml, eclipse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />

        <solid android:color="@color/blue900" />
    </shape></item>
<item><shape>
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />

        <solid android:color="@color/blue900" />
    </shape></item>
```

Even if I did auto formatting ( ctlr+shift+f ) in eclipse, It is rather dirty.
Such as  < shape > tag is located beside < item > tag, not under it.

Also I set **preference >> XML >> XML Files >> Editor** which is general setting .
(I really sorry that I can't post an image due to lack of 10 reputations)
What is the problem and what should I do for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Tools use their own formatting preferences, not the ones defined for the regular XML Editor. I'm not sure where you configure that, though.

Comment: Thank you very much ! you gave me a hint inspiring for resolving this problem.
I set the **Preference>>Android>>Editors>>Format XML files using ~ part unchecked**, and I got it. I think another XML formatter which i downloaded before conflicts android's own formatter.